# Can I block Inheritance in Azure

Tags: azure, inheritance

can someone please help me with the following question

if I have an Azure Subscription, Resource Group then an Azure Key Vault in that resource group can I block inheritance from the Subscription and Resource group so users with rights at the subscription and resource group level do not automatically inherited the rights (like contributor or owner etc.) to the Key Vault. I see I cannot delete the permissions at the key Vault level as the permissions are inherited. However I may still want someone to have say contributor at the subscription or resource group level but have lesser or no rights on the Key Vault itself

Please advise, thanks in advance
__AAnotherUser

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for what you're looking for might be locks if this is the only resource you want to lock down:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-lock-resources

There are also more granular RBAC setups than just giving someone full owner/contributor access: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-custom-roles

Comment: Thanks very much Travis :)

Comment: @Travis_H, I tried the lock approach and it did not stop the inheritance from being applied.

Comment: The lock approach is not to stop inheritance, it simply makes a resource un-changeable. Assume you have a very important resource that should not be tampered with. There are some users that have Owner or Contributor rights on the Subscription and inherited to the Resource Group. The administrator can lock the resource, such that the Owners and Contributors cannot modify the resource without removing the lock, which can only be done by Administrators.

Comment: What if there are hundred resources in the resource group, I don't want anyone to tamper 99 of them, but one. I don't want to put in an individual lock on the rest just because of one resource. What do we do then?